# Install package not in repositories so that dpkg knows about it

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compile

I am trying to compile some software for my raspberry. During the configuration process, the following appears:

```
configure: error: Requested 'libavcodec >= 55.0.0' but version of libavcodec is 54.35.0.
```

I have downloaded and compiled the source for ffmpeg, which I think includes that librery, but the error persists.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What software are you compiling? How can we reproduce this issue?

Comment: Im compiling vlc, with hw acceleration support

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `equivs`to create a pseudo-package, so that dpkg knows about your installed software. See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.html